# Unable to read keystore file from pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, jks

I'm using below snippet to connect and load data from Hive to elasticsearch(v 6.2) without any issues

```
ADD JAR file:///<>/elasticsearch-hadoop-hive-6.2.2.jar;
ADD FILE file:///<>/mycerts.jks;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE if not exists my_db.my_es_table
(
col1 int,
col2 string,
col3 string,
col4 timestamp,
key_id string
)
COMMENT 'data into ES'
STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES('es.resource' = 'index1/type1',
'es.index.auto.create'='true',
'es.nodes'='<vip_name>',
'es.port'='9200',
'es.net.http.auth.user'='<user>',
'es.net.http.auth.pass'='pwd',
'es.net.ssl.protocol'='SSL',
'es.net.ssl'='TRUE',
'es.net.ssl.truststore.location'='mycerts.jks',
'es.net.ssl.truststore.pass'='<pwd>',
'es.mapping.id'='key_id'
);

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE my_db.my_es_table
SELECT
col1,
col2,
col3,
col4,
key_id
FROM my_db.stagging_data;
```

But, when am trying to migrate the same piece to py-spark, it is throwing exceptions

```
   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Expected to find keystore file at [file:///<path>/mycerts.jks] but was unable to. Make sure that it is available on the classpath, or if not, that you have specified a valid URI
```

Below is the code snippet i have tried for spark

```
df_delta=sqlContext.table('my_db.stagging_data')
status=df_delta.rdd.map(lambda row:(None,row.asDict())).saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(path='-', outputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat",keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable",conf={'es.resource' : 'index1/type1','es.index.auto.create':'true','es.nodes':'<vip_name>','es.port':'9200','es.net.http.auth.user':'<user>','es.net.http.auth.pass':'<pwd>','es.net.ssl':'true','es.net.ssl.truststore.location':'file:///<path>/mycerts.jks','es.net.ssl.truststore.pass':'<pwd>','es.mapping.id' : 'key_id'})
```

I'm calling the shell using below command -

```
pyspark --jars <path>/elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-6.2.2.jar --py-files <path>/mycerts.jks
```

Below i'm adding entire log

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Expected to find keystore file at [file:///<path>/mycerts.jks] but was unable to. Make sure that it is available on the classpath, or if not, that you have specified a valid URI.
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.commonshttp.SSLSocketFactory.loadKeyStore(SSLSocketFactory.java:193)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.commonshttp.SSLSocketFactory.loadTrustManagers(SSLSocketFactory.java:224)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.commonshttp.SSLSocketFactory.createSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:171)
        ... 31 more

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1609)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1597)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1596)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1596)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1830)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1779)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1768)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2055)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2087)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalStateException: Cannot initialize SSL - Expected to find keystore file at [file:///<path>/mycerts.jks] but was unable to. Make sure that it is available on the classpath, or if not, that you have specified a valid URI.
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.commonshttp.SSLSocketFactory.createSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:173)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.commonshttp.SSLSocketFactory.getSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:158)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.commonshttp.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:127)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.commonshttp.CommonsHttpTransport.execute(CommonsHttpTransport.java:478)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.NetworkClient.execute(NetworkClient.java:112)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:380)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:344)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:348)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.get(RestClient.java:158)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.getHttpNodes(RestClient.java:115)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverNodesIfNeeded(InitializationUtils.java:92)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.createWriter(RestService.java:579)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat$EsRecordWriter.init(EsOutputFormat.java:173)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat$EsRecordWriter.write(EsOutputFormat.java:149)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceWriteConfigUtil.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:356)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1413)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:139)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Expected to find keystore file at [file:///<path>/mycerts.jks] but was unable to. Make sure that it is available on the classpath, or if not, that you have specified a valid URI.
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.commonshttp.SSLSocketFactory.loadKeyStore(SSLSocketFactory.java:193)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.commonshttp.SSLSocketFactory.loadTrustManagers(SSLSocketFactory.java:224)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.commonshttp.SSLSocketFactory.createSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:171)
        ... 31 more
```

I'm able to read and print the jks file after connecting to py-spark. Unable to resolve this issue. Could some one please suggest.

Comment: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-7-x/topics/sg_spark_auth.html

Comment: Are you sure that the following path is correct `file:///<path>/mycerts.jks`?? Looks like `<path>` should be replace by a real path, doesn't it?

Comment: @Val - Path is absolute only. I have replaced it for security reasons

Answer (score 4):

I think you're using the wrong option

> For Python, you can use the `--py-files` argument of spark-submit to add **.py, .zip or .egg files** to be distributed with your application

Instead you want `--files`

> `--files FILES: Comma-separated list of files to be placed in the working directory of each executor. File paths of these files in executors can be accessed via SparkFiles.get(fileName)`

To place it at a different path within the executor, then you can use `#` separator

```
spark-submit ... --files mycerts.jks#/<path>/mycerts.jks
```

Within the code, you can get a reference to the path from `SparkFiles.get("mycerts.jks")`, which returns the absolute path to the file

Comment: Thanks for the detail. I have tried the --files option but still facing the same issue..
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Expected to find keystore file at

Comment: I'm fairly sure this option is correct, but you'll have to adjust the path at which you're reading the file. I'm not sure that absolute paths work... Otherwise, you would need to distribute the JKS file to each of the servers in your Spark cluster

Answer (score 0):

Based on your stack message it seems your  `<path` is clearly wrong. Your  **path** value after `--jars` and  `--py-files` should be accurate but alas it's currently not.

> Expected to find keystore file at [file:////mycerts.jks] but
>   was unable to. Make sure that it is available on the classpath, or if
>   not, that you have specified a valid URI.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by cricket_007 above, you are using incorrect option --py-files. Instead use --files option to upload your cert files.

Also, these files are not uploaded in the local filesystem of these executors but on HDFS. Thus the the path you are passing for the cert file in your spark code is also incorrect as it is pointing to local filesystem.

```
'es.net.ssl.truststore.location':'file:///<path>/mycerts.jks'
```

You can use the # separator with files option in your spark submit command to upload the file on a specified on HDFS

```
spark-submit ... --files mycerts.jks#/<path>/mycerts.jks
```

and then use the same path in your spark code to access the file.

```
'es.net.ssl.truststore.location':'/<path>/mycerts.jks'
```

Comment: I thought files were uploaded to executor classpath, not HDFS

Comment: Afaik, they are uploaded in the staging area by spark and shared by all the executors.